# Optimize/Refactor Javascript Unique Array function

Tags: javascript, optimization

This is one idea of implementation:

```
 Array.prototype.unique = function () {
  unique_array = [];
  for (var i = 0, l = this.length; i < l; i++) {
    if(unique_array.indexOf(this[i]) == -1){
      unique_array.push(this[i]);
    }
  }
  return unique_array;
 }
```

This version uses Object.keys which is a ECMAScript 5 only feature, as you can see on this website http://kangax.github.com/es5-compat-table/

```
Array.prototype.unique_e5 = function () {
  unique_object = {};
  for (var i = 0, l = this.length; i < l; i++) {
    unique_object[this[i]] = 1;
  }
  return Object.keys(unique_object);
}
```

And this is how is done in prototype.js 
https://github.com/sstephenson/prototype/blob/master/src/prototype/lang/array.js

```
 /**
   *  Array#uniq([sorted = false]) -> Array
   *  - sorted (Boolean): Whether the array has already been sorted. If `true`,
   *    a less-costly algorithm will be used.
   *
   *  Produces a duplicate-free version of an array. If no duplicates are
   *  found, the original array is returned.
   *
   *  On large arrays when `sorted` is `false`, this method has a potentially
   *  large performance cost.
   *
   *  ##### Examples
   *
   *      [1, 3, 2, 1].uniq();
   *      // -> [1, 2, 3]
   *
   *      ['A', 'a'].uniq();
   *      // -> ['A', 'a'] (because String comparison is case-sensitive)
  **/
  function uniq(sorted) {
    return this.inject([], function(array, value, index) {
      if (0 == index || (sorted ? array.last() != value : !array.include(value)))
        array.push(value);
      return array;
    });
  }
```

Also not that the prototype version uses the Prototype **enumerable method include**, which is:

```
 /**
   *  Enumerable#include(object) -> Boolean
   *  - object (?): The object to look for.
   *
   *  Determines whether a given object is in the enumerable or not,
   *  based on the `==` comparison operator (equality with implicit type
   *  conversion).
   *
   *  ##### Examples
   *
   *      $R(1, 15).include(10);
   *      // -> true
   *
   *      ['hello', 'world'].include('HELLO');
   *      // -> false ('hello' != 'HELLO')
   *
   *      [1, 2, '3', '4', '5'].include(3);
   *      // -> true ('3' == 3)
  **/
  function include(object) {
    if (Object.isFunction(this.indexOf))
      if (this.indexOf(object) != -1) return true;

    var found = false;
    this.each(function(value) {
      if (value == object) {
        found = true;
        throw $break;
      }
    });
    return found;
  }
```

Is there a better way to do it? faster or "better" cross browser compatible?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but I think you're asking a similar question to mine, [on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12041837/javascript-unique-method-for-array-prototype). I was trying to get people to close-vote it, but as luck would have it, it hasn't been closed yet. It's not that good of a fit for SO, and I have my answer and a couple of ppl suggested it to be moved to this site, but I haven't gotten round to that either.

Comment: The issue with using an object is that you won't be able to recognize "__proto__". (ES6 Map solves this issue.) But it's the best algorithm in term of big-o cost so it could be interesting if you're going to have laaaarge arrays.

Comment: (I meant `__proto__`.)

Answer (score 2):

For me, I'd always avoid methods that require lots of includes to things get working - and in my mind, the more code used.. the slower things will be *(unless some form of caching is used)*. Which is why I would opt for a simple JavaScript solution. Your idea will work, but I think this one is faster:

```
Array.prototype.unique = function () {
  var a = this, b = [], c, i = a.length;
  again: while ( i-- ) {
    c = a[i];
    k = i; while( k-- ){ if (a[k] == c){ continue again; } }
    b.unshift( a[i] );
  }
  return b;
}
```

There are probably other improvements that can be made, for example it might be faster to find a way to use .push() rather than .unshift().

I haven't tested the above excessively, but it seems to work in all my tests so far. The reason why it gets a speed increase is because it reduces the area it is checking each time; it is also using subtle other speed increases like a decrementing while loop *(means there are less conditional statements to check on each iteration)*, and creating shortcut vars that cut down access time.

As proof here is a jsPerf... albeit only tested on my set-up so far ;)

http://jsperf.com/compare-array-unique-versions

**side note:** -- the downside to my method is that it will only include the last found occurance of a duplicate *(not the first as your's will)*. So if that ordering is important to you, then you'll have to refactor the code.

**revision:** -- after a few jsPerfs it seems clear that the `while(i--)` no longer holds a speed difference *(at least not for FireFox 16 Mac OSX)*. Whilst on Chrome Mac OSX `i--;` seems slower than `i++;`

http://jsperf.com/compare-a-dec-while-against-a-for-loop

So taking in to account BillyBarry's comments the improved version should be:

```
Array.prototype.unique8 = function () {
  var a = this, b = [], c, i, l = a.length, j, k = 0;
  again: for ( i = 0; i < l; i++ ) {
    c = a[i];
    for ( j = 0; j < k; j++ ) { if (b[j] === c){ continue again; } }
    b[k++] = c;
  }
  return b;
}
```

Working from `b`, rather than `a` improves things quite a lot. Plus using `k++;` rather than `.length` for the internal loop makes quite a bit of difference for FireFox (Mac OSX) but has no affect on Chrome.

Comment: It would be slightly faster to use `b.push()` than unshift, but it will be significantly faster to change the inner loop to loop over `b` instead of `a` if you know that it has many repetitions. see: http://jsperf.com/compare-array-unique-versions/2

Comment: +1 Yep, I was pretty certain .push() would be better - and from looking at your jsPerf I'm surprised the for loop version seems to win out *(I guess that while trick is no longer true in recent interpreters - need to refresh my assumptions ;)*. Good point about interating over b instead - I was trying to cut down on variable usage and length checks but it seems these don't impact so much.

Comment: Ah, actually, have just added another revision not using .length *(keeping track of the length by incrementing a var instead)* and that made quite a bit of difference http://jsperf.com/compare-array-unique-versions/4

Answer (score 2):

Here's my version, however there are three major downsides.

- Requires more memory.
- Only works with primitive datatypes or objects with a string method that returns unique values. In other words, this doesn't work with objects or object literals.
- Harder to read and maintain

### Code:

```
Array.prototype.getUnique = function () {
    var arr = this;
    var newArr = [],
    i = 0,
    j = 0,
    obj = {},
    len = arr.length;
    while (len--) {
        if (!obj[arr[i]]) {
            obj[arr[i]] = 1;
            newArr[j] = arr[i];
            j++;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return newArr;
};
```

Demo here:
http://jsperf.com/compare-array-unique-versions/3

### Update

Here's the same code but revised to make it easier to read.

```
Array.prototype.getUnique_simple = function () {
    var arr = this, newArr = [], obj = {};
    for(var i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; i++){
        if (obj[arr[i]]) {
            continue;
        }
        obj[arr[i]] = 1;
        newArr.push(arr[i]);
    }
    return newArr;
};
```